# useLazyQuery not being called after onClick

Tags: typescript, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

I'm trying to check if my user isLoggedIn with a query from GraphQL API data from the user if it's loggedin if not it's supposed to return undefined or some error.

The question is I have a func called `removeSession` that deletes from my localStorage the token when users click in the logout button. The problem starts now, I've realized that my token was being cleared from localStorage but the userLAzyQuery wasn't get triggered after. So to inspect I started to delete de token manually and after the onClick I invoked the `sendQuery()`

To force my inspection I created `onCompleted` and `onError` callback after the query, and guess what? not being called either.

**header.js**

```
import { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { isAuthenticatedQuery } from '../queries';
import { useQuery, useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import Router from 'next/router';

function isActive(pathname) {
  return typeof document !== 'undefined' && document.location.pathname === pathname;
}

const Header = () => {
  const { loading, data: dataAuth, error } = useQuery(isAuthenticatedQuery);

  const [sendQuery, { data: dataAuthLazy, error: errorsLazy }] = useLazyQuery(isAuthenticatedQuery, {
    onCompleted(data) {
      console.log('invoked onCompleted', data);
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log('onerror', err);
    },
  });

  function removeSession() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    sendQuery();
    console.log('inside removeSession');
    Router.push('/');
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="left">
        <Link href="/">
          <a data-active={isActive('/')}>Blog</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/drafts">
          <a data-active={isActive('/drafts')}>Drafts</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        {!!dataAuth || !!dataAuthLazy ? (
          <Fragment>
            <Link href="/create">
              <a data-active={isActive('/create')}>+ Create draft</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/login" >
              <a onClick={() => sendQuery()}>Logout</a>
            </Link>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <Link href="/signup">
              <a data-active={isActive('/signup')}>Signup</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/login">
              <a data-active={isActive('/login')}>Login</a>
            </Link>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        nav {
          display: flex;
          padding: 2rem;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .bold {
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: gray;
          font-weight: regular;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .left a[data-active='true'] {
          color: #000;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        a + a {
          margin-left: 1rem;
        }

        .right {
          margin-left: auto;
        }

        .right a {
          padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background: hsla(0, 89%, 63%, 0.79);
          color: white;
          font-weight: 500;
        }

        .right a:hover {
          background: hsl(0, 72%, 54%);
        }
      `}</style>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**queries/index.ts**

```
export const isAuthenticatedQuery = gql`
  query isAuthenticatedQuery {
    me {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm using next.js, apollo 3, react16.12 FYI

In my network tabs no signal of some XHR activity

**Update 1**: I added `fetchPolicy` in my lazyQuery and my request appeared in chromedev tools but with status canceled

```
  const [sendQuery, { data: dataAuthLazy, error: errorsLazy }] = useLazyQuery(isAuthenticatedQuery, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    onCompleted(data) {
      console.log('invoked onCompleted', data);
      Router.push('/');
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log('onerror', err);
    },
  });
```

Comment: `await sendQuery();` or move  `Router.push('/');` into `onCompleted`

Comment: its not calling onCompleted... and await didn't worked =(

Comment: disable/comment out `Router.push` ?

Comment: @DanielRearden Still not working, I'm quite sure that's not a problem of router because when I click I can invoke my `removeSession` function but the statement `sendQuery()` is not being called!

Answer (score 15):

You're already running the same query when the component mounts here:

```
const { loading, data: dataAuth, error } = useQuery(isAuthenticatedQuery)
```

That means, by default, subsequent fetches of the same query will be fulfilled from the cache. This is why you don't see anything in the Network tab.

In order to force the request to be fulfilled by the server, we need to change the fetch policy to something like `network-only`:

```
const [sendQuery, { data: dataAuthLazy, error: errorsLazy }] = useLazyQuery(isAuthenticatedQuery, {
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
})
```

I would expect `onCompleted` to be executed regardless of how the query was fulfilled, but I can't speak to whether that is intended behavior or a bug.

Comment: I'm still learning about apollo, started weeks ago but I think it's necessary to make the same query. The first query is when the user have the token in their local storage, and useLazy is triggered only when the user clicks at the logout button.

Comment: Now I can see my request, but my REQUEST header that is supposed to be POST is not defined and my request is canceled. I've never seen a request without the request method.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike if you used `useMutation`, `sendQuery` returns undefined instead of a Promise. That means you can't wait for the query to finish before calling `Router.push`. So the query is kicked off and then your component is unmounted, causing the query to be cancelled.

Comment: There's an open issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3499) to change the API to address this. That same issue includes a couple of work arounds you could use.

Comment: Unfortunately still an issue, the useLazyQuery doesn't return a promise. So I've made a workaround by checking localStorage value, not the best way but patience.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this SO page looking for solution to a very close problem. For me, after the first failure, the `onError` function wasn't being called for the subsequent error calls.

Adding `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` worked well for me.

Code Snippet:

```
     getAccountsQuery,
            {
              fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
              onCompleted: (data) => {
              /// 
              },
              notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, // did the work
              onError: (error) => {
                setAccountsApiError(error);
              },
            }
          );
```